# Less, Joomla and Gantry development

Tags: joomla, less, cache-control

I am trying to design a Gantry template for Joomla with less. It doesn´t work. No updates.

I´ve tried every solution i've found on the internet now.

My less changes doesn´t  work/updates.

This is what I done/do:

In Joomla: Turned off all Joomla cache functions in configuration and plug-ins. I clear cache both in Joomla configuration and Gantry Theme after updates. I also use NoNumber Cache Cleaner plug-in. In my index.php header I have entered: [header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");] and [header("Pragma: no-cache");]

In files: I use Gantrys file naming [menu.less -> menu-custom.less]. The files "Modified" time stamp on the remote server are right/updated. The code are right in those files.
But when I check the code with Firebug the old code is still there.

Browser: Private Browsning in Firefox

Nothing works. Updates doesn´t show up.

What more can I do?

Best regards

/Magnus

Comment: Your question is too vague and broad to be answered as is.  With the info you've given it could be utterly anything wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. Its hard to describe everything in english for me. Since the files are updated on the server but not showing up in the code my conclusion are that it´s a cache issue or that the new updated code not being compiled to css as Gantry should on an update.

Comment: Does Gantry compile LESS for you?

Comment: Never mind. I see that it does. http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/advanced/less_css.md

Comment: RustProof Labs is right, though. Can you show a demo?

Comment: I´ve had some luck now. But it seems like it´s randomly chooses to update changes i´ve done. Here is my site: http://hantverkshuset.vinkallangruppen.se

Comment: The time might have something to do with it too. But I really need to get updates to work instantly. Otherwise I wount be done for years!